# Are there earphones with support for buttons similar to the OEM earphones?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.1-jelly-bean

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII plus. In the package I also got earphones from Samsung. The problem is that those earphones are in-ear, and they don't fit me well. I was wondering if there are 3rd-party earphones with the same capabilities (a pause/play button is what I like the most, but volume control and a microphone are also welcome) that is not too expensive.

I could only find earphones with that capabilities for iPhones, so is there a way to some transform this input so android can read it?

I would really like your advice on this matter, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the iPhone headphones with controls work. And this isn't really the place for product suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Arjan! Please note that shopping recommendations are off topic at all StackExchange sites. You might want to check [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "android headphones" at Amazon.com